# Directive @class reports the code in red as shown in the present image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

As mentioned in the title, the @class directive signals the code in red as shown in the image below.

How can this error be resolved?

Also, is it possible to color the code? It is shown all white, difficult to read

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written there is correct, shouldn't produce any error.
Regarding the colors should check the theme of the IDE you are using..

Comment: why is it marked in red?

Comment: Don't know that but it's not an error. Probably color schema